# Unit Testing React HashRouter with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am desperately trying to Unit Test my HashRouter routes but cannot get my head around how. I managed to get a solution using Enzyme but am forced to use ReactTestingLibrary by tech lead.

Can anyone help out pointing me in the right direction?

**App Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { create } from 'jss';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/styles';

import './App.css';
import Routes from './Routes';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Routes />                                      
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Routes Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import NetworksList from './pages/NetworksList';
import DealsList from './pages/DealsList';

class Routes extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path="/networks" component={NetworksList} />
        <Route path="/deals" component={DealsList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

**App Component Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import Routes from './Routes';


beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});


it.only('should render networks list page at #/networks', () => {

  const history = createMemoryHistory()
  history.push('networks');

  const { container, getByText } = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  )

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to use hash based history 'createHashHistory', for testing Hash based router. I have put together a working example for this Hash Router React Testing Library navigation example. https://codesandbox.io/s/hashrouter-react-router-react-testing-library-njmj5

For example, your App.jsx is:

```
import Routes from "./Routes";
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>HashRouter Testing</h1>
      <Router>
        <ul className="nav justify-content-center">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
              CompOne
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#/comp-two">
              CompTwo
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And Routes.jsx is:

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const CompOne = () => <div>Component One</div>;
const CompTwo = () => <div>Component Two</div>;

export default function Routes(props) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <CompOne />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/comp-two">
        <CompTwo />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Then, here is how you can test hash based navigation :

```
import React from "react";
import { render, wait, waitForElement } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { createHashHistory } from "history";
import App from "./App";

describe("AppRouter component", () => {
  afterEach(jest.resetAllMocks);

  it("navigates correctly", async () => {
    const history = createHashHistory({ initialEntries: ["/"] });
    history.push("/comp-two");
    const { container, getByText, debug } = render(<App />);
    await waitForElement(() => getByText(/Component Two/i));
    debug();
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: For anyone who's reached this answer while looking for a Jest/jsdom equivalent, in your test file you need to define `window.location.hash` before calling `createHashHistory()`, because jsdom doesn't have it by default and the call will fail with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined`. Do this first: `Object.defineProperty(window.location, "hash", { writable: true, value: "#" });` (where `#` is whatever URI fragment you're starting off at).